# How can I capture SQL Server trace events when inserting large data chunk into binary column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I want to record all SQL statements that hit my server to replay it later. But it seems that neither SQL Server traces nor events do capture the insertion of large data chunks into binary columns.

I have an insert statement like this:

```
INSERT [dbo].[my_table] ([Id], [File]) VALUES (1, x0FEWREWD4EFAxFDS5GFDSxx0FEWREWD4EFAxFDS5GFDSxx0FEWREWD4EFAxFDS5GFDSxEFAxFDS5GFDSxx0x0FEWREWD4EFAxFDS5GFDSxx0FEWREWD4EFAxFDS5GFDSxx0FEWREWD4EFAxFDS5GFDSxEFAxFDS5GFDSxx0x0FEWREWD4EFAxFDS5GFDSxx0FEWREWD4EFAxFDS5GFDSxx0FEWREWD4EFAxFDS5GFDSxEFAxFDS5GFDSxx0x0FEWREWD4EFAxFDS5GFDSxx0FEWREWD4EFAxFDS5GFDSxx0FEWREWD4EFAxFDS5GFDSxEFAxFDS5GFDSxx0....
```

Is there a way to capture the inserts of binary data with SQL server traces/events?

Comment: `sql_statement_starting` and `sp_statement_starting` *should* capture the whole of the statement, but it depends on your trace target and how you read it whether you'll get all of it. The ring buffer target (used in the background if you set up an ad-hoc session in SSMS) has a well-known limit of 4 MB for the XML it outputs, for example. An event file target doesn't have that limitation.

Comment: @Jeroen your hint with the memory limit led me to review the extended settings of my event session. There I found an option to set the event retention mode to not losing any events. I think this was the trick. Now I get the binary inserts with the events I already captured - `rpc_completed` and `sql_batch_completed`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that setting the retention mode in the advanced settings of the event session to never lose an event does the trick.

[image]